# Bounty auto-select in the case of a tie

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

When someone asks a question and puts a bounty on it, but doesn't select an answer, the bounty goes to the highest voted answer with at least two up-votes. What happens when two answers are tied?

Comment: From the [Bounty FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) "What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered?" - 
The answer with the most votes is automatically accepted after 7 days. The bounty is subtracted from your reputation. The answerer is awarded half the bounty amount. **If more than one answer is tied with most votes, the first answer receives the award.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @ccomet's answer-comment:
From the [Bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067):

> The answer with the most votes is automatically accepted after 7 days. The bounty is subtracted from your reputation. The answerer is awarded half the bounty amount. **If more than one answer is tied with most votes, the first answer receives the award.**

Emphasis ccomet's/mine.  Posted so there can be an accepted answer on this question.  Marked CW only because I don't deserve rep for this.

Comment: @mmyers From the [acceptance FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) (and converting a bullet list to a comma list) "Which questions do not affect the accept rate?" The following questions are not included in the accept rate calculation: Community Wiki Questions, Closed Questions, Questions with no answers

Comment: @Popular: You said "Posted so there can be an accepted answer on this question", so I thought that's what you were talking about.

Comment: @mmyers, I posted so it wouldn't clutter up the Unanswered Questions tab.  But either way, I couldn't have posted my answer _after_ the question was closed.

Comment: I can't post a relevant FAQ entry because it isn't actually stated there (curses! No 3 for 3!), but a manual examination of the 16 pages of Unanswered Questions shows no questions that are closed. So I think it can be safe to say that closed questions are not added to the Unanswered Questions tab.

Comment: @Popular Demand: You posted when there were 4 close votes, but I see now that you're under 3k so you couldn't have known that. And either way, there's no harm done; I just thought you might have had a misconception. :)

Comment: @mmyers: Wow.  Way to rub my low rep in my face.  Jerk.  (I'm kidding, of course; I appreciate your intent to help.  The "discovery" that there are no closed "Unanswered" questions is nice, too.)